# Ignore null values on MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for users to enter some information. After the form being submitted, it should query a database with the values that the user entered.

My problem here is that if some of the values that the user entered are null, it should remove from the query.

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include("../includes/header.php");
include ("../scripts/db/connect.php");

//Gets variables from $_POST
$negocio = $_POST['negocio'];
$imovel = $_POST['imovel'];
$distrito = $_POST['distrito'];
$concelho = $_POST['concelho'];
$freguesia = $_POST['freguesia'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE negocio = $negocio and imovel = $imovel and distrito = $distrito and concelho = $concelho and freguesia = $freguesia";
}
```

Imagine if `$negocio`, `$imovel`, `$concelho` and `$freguesia` are equal to `null`, the query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE distrito = $distrito;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use `OR`'s instead of `AND`'s or use a subquery with a CASE, along with a `IS NULL`. Your variables are unclear if they're strings or not and the db schema for this.

Comment: Sorry, my variables are just int.

Comment: Alexandre you have two answer and both are correct, read them once more if you are confuse

Comment: I would call a stored proc and pass in all parameters not checking for null in php code. Once the parameters are in the stored proc, I would simply use a SELECT statement with WHERE clause and use OR between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Generate your query string dynamcilly depending on which value are set
>   or not null, and than use that query

**Run this code in a seperate file you will understand the point, after removing or adding comment to any variable, ($name,$street, $address or $qualification )**

```
// you will see query will change depending on the set variable,
//I am using these name you can use any name for your variable

$name='my name';
//$address='some where on earth';
$street='this is my street';
//$qualification='i am very much qualified';

//now create the array only with the values which are not empty or not nul,
//I am using empty you can use null if you want with this example you can use any thing.
if(!empty($name)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND name = '$name'";
if(!empty($address)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND address = '$address'";
if(!empty($street)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND street = '$street'";
if(!empty($qualification)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND qualification = '$qualification'";

//hand type the first part for the query
$query_string_First_Part= "SELECT * FROM myTableName WHERE";
//Implode the array, if you want to see how it look like use echo,
$query_string_second_part= implode(" ", $query_string_second_part);
//as you can see we are adding AND with every value, so we need to remove the first AND
//with one space
//Make sure you give space in the second parameter. else it wont work means "" not correct but " " is correct
//Hint --> use one space in between the double qoutes
$query_string_second_part=  preg_replace("/AND/", " ", $query_string_second_part, 1);

//Join the first and second part together to create a full query
$query_string=$query_string_First_Part.$query_string_second_part;
echo ($query_string);//see how our query look like at the moment
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an input null check to each clause.  So for example where you do this:

```
distrito = $distrito
```

You might instead do this:

```
(distrito = $distrito or $distrito IS NULL)
```

or perhaps:

```
(distrito = $distrito or $distrito = '')
```

Depending on the data types, the actual input being used to build the query, etc.  Might take some tweaking and debugging when manually building a query like this (I suspect using prepared statements with query parameters will make this cleaner, as well as more secure), but the idea is the same either way.

Basically you're instructing it to match the row based on the value, or match the row based on the lack of value.  So for any given clause, if the supplied value is null/empty, then all rows match and the clause becomes moot.

Comment: I don't understand your idea. If I try to query with a null value, it will return results that have null values

Comment: @AlexandreCristo: The idea is that if you supply a `NULL` value then *all* rows are returned, because that search value is interpreted as not having been used in the search.  Consider what the `(distrito = $distrito or $distrito IS NULL)` for any given value you provide it, `NULL` or otherwise.